# How can I enable 4G/4G split in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory, 32bit, out-of-memory

It is an useful feature for systems which are using (...still have to use) 32-bit binaries, and the 4G limit came into consideration.

It essentially means, that the 32-bit user-space code, the 32-bit user-space data and the (32-bit with PAE, or 64-bit) kernel live in *different* address spaces, which essentially enables for the processes to use nearly all of the possible maximal 4G address space for their data.

Except some [ancient announcements](https://lwn.net/Articles/39283/), unfortunately I couldn't find from it any more:

> I am pleased to announce the first public release of the "4GB/4GB VM
>   split" patch, for the 2.5.74 Linux kernel:
>
> http://redhat.com/~mingo/4g-patches/4g-2.5.74-F8
>
> The 4G/4G split feature is primarily intended for large-RAM x86
>   systems, which want to (or have to) get more kernel/user VM, at the
>   expense of per-syscall TLB-flush overhead.
>
> On x86, the total amount of virtual memory - as we all know - is
>   limited to 4GB. Of this total 4GB VM, userspace uses 3GB
>   (0x00000000-0xbfffffff), the kernel uses 1GB (0xc0000000-0xffffffff).
>   This is VM scheme is called the 3/1 split. This split works perfecly
>   fine up until 1 GB of RAM - and it works adequately well even after
>   that, due to 'highmem', which moves various larger caches (and
>   objects) into the high memory area.

On my tests, some of my processes start to dying roughly at 2-3 GB.

How could I do achieve this? I use a relative recent kernel (4.10). I can use a 64-bit kernel on a 32-bit user space or use a 32-bit PAE kernel.

It is enough, if only some of the processes use 4G/4G, but they seem to really need it.

Comment: You would need to patch the kernel. To my knowledge, the 4G/4G split was never released in the official kernel, and I doubt you will find a patch that applies to a modern kernel. I guess the 33 % improvement over the 3/1 split was not worth it, especially after 64-bit CPUs became the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a 64-bit kernel you already have full 4G accessible by a 32-bit userspace program. See yourself by entering the following in the terminal (WARNING: your system may become unresponsive if it doesn't have free 4GiB of RAM when running this):

```
cd /tmp
cat > test.c <<"EOF"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    size_t allocated=0;
    while(1)
    {
        const size_t chunkSize=4096;
        char* p=malloc(chunkSize);
        if(!p) return 0;
        *p=1;
        allocated+=chunkSize;
        printf("%zu\n",allocated);
    }
    return 0;
}
EOF
gcc test.c -o test -m32 && ./test | tail -n1
```

On my x86_64 kernel 3.12.18 I get `4282097664` as the result, which is about 4GiB-12.3MiB, so it's fair to consider 4G/xG split achieved.